# How to emit items from list with delay between each item?

Tags: list, delay, rx-java

I want to emit items from list and between each of emission I want a delay. I've tried this:

```
final Subscription subscription = Observable.from(listOfItems)
    .delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String sss) {
        }
    });
```

but it just delays the start of emission, not emission of each item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
List<Integer> listOfItems = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        Observable.from(listOfItems)
                .zipWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (item, notUsed) -> item)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you want delay before first emission use `Observable.interval(initialDelay, delay, TimeUnit)`